# perfctl usa el 100% de los recursos del CPU

Tags: cron, digitalocean, cpu

ya llevo varios días intentando eliminar el proceso `perfctl` del servidor que tengo alojado en un VPS en digitalOcean al parecer en un proceso de cronjob pero no logro eliminar

he tratado de matar el proceso con `kill 'numero PID'` pero despues de un rato vuelve a iniciarse el proceso y topa al 100% los recursos del CPU, adjunto imagen de como se mantiene los recursos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejecuté el siguiente comando

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done
```

y me arrojó esto:

```
11 * * * * /root/.config/cron/perfcc
```

pero no se como eliminar este proceso.

Comment: yo busque en google ese nombre, y encontre [esto](https://serverfault.com/questions/1095192/100-cpu-load-caused-by-service-perfctl)

Comment: gracias ya estoy revisando la publicación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera.

revise el crontab con el comando

```
crontab -l
```

el cual me arrojo el siguiente mensaje

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

11 * * * * /root/.config/cron/perfcc
```

luego edite el crontab con

```
crontab -e
```

y eliminé la linea `11 * * * * /root/.config/cron/perfcc`, luego reinicié el servicio de crontab

```
sudo service cron reload
sudo service cron restart
```

**Nota:** este proceso lo hice despues de haber reiniciado **Ubuntu 20.04** para que no se ejecutara el cron por primera vez